# WinRT(Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate)

Tags: windows, html, html5, javascript, visual-studio

Установил Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, хочу разрабатывать приложения для Windows Store на HTML/JS. Но вот проблема.
Захожу в Новый проект. Далее выбираю "Другие языки", у меня есть VB, C++, C#, F#. По идее должен быть еще пункт Javascript но его нет. Что мне делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нет шаблонов проектов для разработки Metro приложений, значит скорее всего Вы поставили Visual Studio на Windows ниже восьмой версии.

> Разработка приложений Магазина Windows в Visual Studio доступна только в Windows 8 и Windows 8.1 Preview. Windows 7 не поддерживается. Кроме того, лицензии разработчика недоступны для Windows Server 2012, поэтому разрабатывать приложения Магазина Windows в этой системе нельзя.

Источник: [Шаблоны для ускорения разработки приложений](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/hh738343.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то для разработки приложений для Windows Store вам нужна специальная версия Visual Studio [Express 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/rus/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-8#product-express-windows), а также предустановленная версия Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/br211386) Вы можете скачать бесплатный образ win8.1 для разработки на ней.